# My abbreviation divides me

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My abbreviation divides me,
>
> in half I would be.
>
> My anagram shares its colour with sage,
>
> Overall, I can be measured with age.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Mile

My abbreviation divides me, 
in half I would be.

> mi is half of the word mile

My anagram shares its colour with sage,

> Lime (green)

Overall, I can be measured with age.

> mile + age = mileage, which is a measure of the number of miles covered.

Answer (score 4):

ok, probably wrong... but

> Earth

My abbreviation divides me,

in half I would be.

> This is a stretch but ♁ is the symbol of Earth, upside down it is the symbol for female, or half the population

My anagram shares its colour with sage

> Heart (purple heart, purple sage)

Overall, I can be measured with age

> Earth time is measured in ages

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> Ohm

My abbreviation divides me,

In half I would be

> An ohm is abbreviated with an omega, which the word ohm is about half of.

My anagram share its color with sage

> Hom is a plant that is green

Overall I can be measured by age

> Ohm-age is how resistance is measured